# How can I get the percentage of each unique value from a column grouped by another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a problem where I have a column filled with the year of the event (2007, 2008, ..., 2019) and another column with the type of the event (event_A, event_B, event_C). I want to know from each year what the percentage of the events B that happened.

Basically, I have this:

```
Year    Event_Type
2007    Event_A
2007    Event_A
2007    Event_B
2007    Event_B
2008    Event_B
2008    Event_B
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
2007    Event_B    50%
2008    Event_B    100%
```

I've been looking for this in a while, but I keep getting to group by posts that are not related to this. So I am still far from achieving the result I want.

The closest I got was by doing:

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Event_Type']).size()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Using `crosstab/pivot` to count the no of occurrences per year followed by slicing `Event_B` column and dividing it by sum of df across `axis=1`

```
c = pd.crosstab(df['Year'],df['Event_Type'])
c.loc[:,'Event_B'].div(c.sum(1),axis=0).mul(100).astype(str).add('%')
```

**Method 2:**

You can use count the no. of times `Event_B` occurs in a group divided by the group size:

```
(df['Event_Type'].eq('Event_B').groupby(df['Year']).sum()
.div(df.groupby('Year').size(),axis=0).mul(100).astype(str).add('%'))
```

---

```
Year
2007     50.0%
2008    100.0%
```